# Firebase Hosting error - added a new domain and added A records but I have been waiting 24 hours

Tags: firebase, dns, firebase-hosting, firebase-dynamic-links

I have a problem with dynamic links. I added a new domain and added A records but I have been waiting 24 hours so I'm getting the same error
I have other A records but with different data and I can't delete them

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I have solved this. I have only put the subdomain without domain in DNS. For example:

subdomain - links.wordbox.ai
only - links

Thanks